# Run MVC2 on IIS6 with DLL's only

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have followed articles on running MVC2 apps on IIS6, but all of those deal with MVC2 being installed on the server.

Are there are known articles/steps on having a straight install of Framework 3.5, setting up IIS6, and just copying required dll's across?

Answer (score 1):

The only difference I would imagine is that instead of running those assemblies from the GAC, they instead reside in your `/bin` directory.  Try setting the MVC assemblies (Mvc/Routing/Abstractions) to have their `CopyLocal` property set to true, and then try deploying to an IIS6 machine that doesn't have MVC installed.  The `CopyLocal` will force those assembly references to be copyed to your output directory.

The only thing which *may* cause an issue is if you are running in Medium trust, as I'm not sure if any of the lower level WebForms page compilation mechanism require elevated trust (which they would be granted if they were GAC'd).